# Crystal report how to get number(which is string with 2 decimal and thousand separator) of the right of sign =

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

how to get a number(which is a string with 2 decimal and thousand separators) of the right of sign '='
I have data as String : "cost = 2,000.50"
and I need only number as 2000.50(which convert to number)

pl sorry for my poor Eng.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string to an array based on the " = " sign and convert the 2nd array element to a number:

```
cDbl(Split({your_text_field}, " = ")[2])
```